# jQuery: How to join sets of selected elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I must be missing something because I've looked around and I just can't find a simple answer to this.

I have many jQuery objects which I'm constructing programmatically:

```
var jq1 = $('#stuff');
var jq2 = $('p.error');
var jq3 = $('<span>Hey!</span>');
/* and so on */
```

**Question**: How to create a jQuery object which is the concatenation of all these objects?

I know I can use the `.add()` method to add a single jQuery selection, so I could do it in a loop and add all these elements one by one, creating a new object with each iteration. Doesn't  jQuery have a way to just join all of these without creating a bunch of new objects?

---

**Update**: I tried to keep it generic, but to give it some more context, what I really want is to generate an unknown number of elements like in the third line. The generated elements will be of unknown type. I will inject them in the DOM, of which I also know nothing about, and then I still need to have a jQuery object containing those elements to manipulate them later.

Comment: Well two are selectors and the other is content generation?!

Comment: you can do `$('#stuff, p.error').add('<span>Hey!</span>')` - multiple selectors for the selector and then `.add()` for element creation

Comment: Thanks, but there will be an arbitrary number of generated elements. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct a jQuery object using an array:

```
var jq1 = $('#stuff');
var jq2 = $('p.error');
var jq3 = $('<span>Hey!</span>');

var $all = $([jq1[0], jq2[0], jq3[0]]);
```

Or, if you have a LOT of elements, and you don't want to mess with all the array indexing:

```
var $all = $([jq1, jq2, jq3].map(function(elt){return elt[0];}));
```

Comment: Well I have to give it to you, it's ugly as hell but it's the only answer so far that directly answers the question correctly. I find it pretty strange that jQuery doesn't have a constructor with an array of jQuery objects instead of an array of DOM elements.

Comment: @btx9000 - because most people don't create a lot of separate jQuery objects in the first place.  You either combine your CSS selectors into one selector that does multiple things (and thus just create one jQuery object in the first place) or, if you're creating things in a loop or in multiple blocks of code, you `.add()` them onto the master as you create them.  Since you refuse to show us the actual code you want help with, the only generic answer to your question is for you to read the jQuery doc page and pick the documented method that fits with your specific code.

Comment: btx9000, it's not the prettiest thing I've ever seen, but I'm not sure I'd go so far to say "ugly as hell!" :).  jfriend00, I don't entirely agree.  the problem I have with `.add()` is that it doesn't add in place: it returns a new jQuery object, so when I use it in this context, I have to do this: `$things = $things.add($thing);`  I think it would be great if jQuery had a `.push()` method.

Comment: I actually use this technique a fair amount, usually during validation.  If I'm bulk validating a bunch of fields, I push ones that failed onto an array.  When I'm done, I construct a jQuery object with all the failed fields and do jQuery-y stuff with them.  And yes, there are good reasons why I don't want to do the jQuery-y stuff with them when I validate the individual field.  Anyway, I've found this technique helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can either combine all the selectors into one selector string that is the union of all elements or you can combine your jQuery objects with `.add()` or some combination of the two.

```
var jqAll = $('#stuff, p.error').add('<span>Hey!</span>');
```

If using `.add()` you must remember that it returns a new jQuery object (it does not just add something to an existing jQuery object).

---

If you're generating a bunch of DOM objects and you want them all in one jQuery object, then you can just create an array of DOM objects and add them all at once to one jQuery object.  You can do that a couple of ways.  If you have an array of domObjects already in an array called `domObjects`.  Then, you can just operate on the array directly to put them all into a single jQuery object like this:

```
var jqAll = $(domObjects);
```

Or, if you want to add them all to an existing jQuery object:

```
var jqAll = $('#stuff, p.error').add(domObjects);
```

Comment: I didn't explain my question well maybe. As said, I know I can use the add method and I know it returns a new object, and that's what I want to avoid, because I will be generating an unknown number of elements in a loop and I need a selection of all of them.

Comment: @btx9000 - then why not just use `.add()` in the loop. If you want help with a loop, you need to show some code in a loop?  Otherwise, we really have no idea what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Just like I say in the question -- I want to avoid a loop to avoid creating many objects that will never be used.

Comment: @btx9000 - it is very hard to figure out what you really want help with here.  If you have an array of dom objects and you want to put them all in one jQuery object in one operation, you can pass the entire array at once (see what I added to my answer).  If this isn't what you want, then I'm at a loss as to what problem you want help with.

Comment: I don't have an array of DOM elements. I have an array of jQuery selections.

Comment: @btx9000 - What is an array of jQuery selections?  Do you mean an array of jQuery objects?  Why don't you just show it with code so it is entirely clear?  We're going on 6 days here and you haven't yet clearly communicated what you're trying to do.  The exact code you have is usually the best way to do that.

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear and tells you all you need to know. You have many, many, many $ objects, the kind of object you get after $('<li></li>'). I call them jQuery objects or jQuery selections. How do you end up with a single $ object which contains all the others? I ended up doing the workaround of doing a loop with $elems = $elems.add($el). What this does is create a new $ object for each iteration of the loop, which seems wasteful and performance poor. The question is how this can be avoided.

Comment: Just to be clear here, this is not something I'm stuck with. There are ways to do this, but they all seem bad. I opened the question not to be able to do something but because it seems unbelievable there isn't a simple standard way to do something so trivial.

Answer (score 1):

For selecting things from the DOM together use:

```
$('#stuff, p.error') // notice separated with comma to act as an 'and'
```

For the rest use .add(). Don't worry about 'creating lots of objects' They are all just pointing to each other, it doesn't really hurt anything.

Remember, you can use a bunch of .add's in-line if you want to:

```
$('#stuff').add('p.error').add('<span>Hey!</span>').add('<p>hello world</p>'); // and so on
```

Comment: Alright now we're getting somewhere. Could you please provide a reference that shows that calling add() many times doesn't hurt performance or memory?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily combine selectors `var jq1 = $('#stuff, p.error');` but the third is generating a new DOM element. I wouldn't recommend combining that, because it doesn't yet exist in the DOM, you likely will have code that assumes it's all in the DOM.

Comment: No I don't have code that assumes that it is in the DOM, it's fine. Actually what I want is exactly to generate multiple elements. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unknown number of results in your object, and you want to convert them to a single html string without a manual loop, then this is quick and dirty.

If they're all siblings and you don't mind updating the visible DOM:

```
var html = $jQuery(massiveSet).wrapAll('<div>').parent().html();
```

You may want to clone first if you don't want to change the elements in the DOM as they already show, or if they're not siblings:

```
var html = $jQuery(massiveSet).clone().wrapAll('<div>').parent().html();
```

You can then put that back into your dom wherever you like:

```
$('body').append(html);
```